# A numeric up and down in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a numeric up and down in HTML?

Comment: There are many jQuery plugins available for this.  Searching took 2 seconds to find one:  http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/06/numeric-up-down-input-jquery/

Comment: The issue is underspecified. What, exactly, do you mean by "numeric up and down"? Are you looking for character entities? Widgets?

Comment: I am not looking for asp. I need one in html or jquery....and i am looking for like 1,2,3,4,5,6....and so on

Comment: Check out Kendo UI's numeric text box: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/numerictextbox/index.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use an HTML5 [`<input type="number"/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29).

More reading at [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number). Browser compatibility tables at [When can I use Number input type?](http://caniuse.com/input-number)

Comment: this looks awesome in chrome but the up/down buttons are not showing up in internet exploder -.-

Comment: Hi, @Matt Internet Explorer does not support up down keys for input control. is there any way other than key events for this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the tag `input` with `type="number"`

```
<input type="number">
```

Here is a usage example on how to use the NumericUpDown:

```js
document.getElementById("square").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  var nudMax = document.getElementById("max").value;

  result.innerHTML = nudMax * nudMax;
});
```

```html
<label for="max">Max</label>
<input id="max" type="number">

<button id="square">Square</button>

<br>

<label for="result">Result:</label>
<output id="result"></output>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of numeric steppers out there. Look for "numeric stepper" or "numeric spinner".

http://xflatlinex.github.io/Numeric-Stepper/

Comment: The link also has an implementation of the html5 data attribute for a type=numeric if your browser is compatible.

Comment: Link is dead. Googling link provides this match: https://bitbucket.org/___flatline___/numeric-stepper

Comment: Hey, I just found this looking at my server's logs haha. Thanks for sharing! I fixed the link, it actually points to http://xflatlinex.github.com/Numeric-Stepper, the project's now hosted on github.